# Does Outlook strip attachments when forwarding from Junk folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I had to forward an email which I found had been placed in the Junk folder because of external sender. Anyway I forwarded it only to be contacted by then recipient that the attachments are missing. I then marked it "Not Junk" and forwarded it again. This time the attachments were there.

This made me think there's some default policy in Outlook to do this, is that the case? I also found an old [experts-exchange thread](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27087391/Junk-E-Mail-being-stripped-of-attachments.html) (not sure if exactly the same case though):

> This user told me she couldn't find an email that someone said they sent her.  I looked with her, and we found it in the Junk E-Mail folder.  She right-clicked on the message and did the "don't mark as spam" or however Outlook 2007 words it.  Then she dragged it to her Inbox.  That worked fine, as we would expect, but there was supposed to be an attachment with the email.  In the act of being sent to Junk E-Mail, does Exhcange or Outlook strip the email of attachments?  If so, is there anyway to retrieve them once you've marked the email as okay?

Comment: It would not be the same. The quoted problem describes that the attachment would be stripped from the E-Mail. So you would be unable to access the attachment at all. As per your own description the attachment was present. The junk mail folder does have special properties (e.g. default text display and warning while clicking on links).